# Gimp - Brush Editor grayed out and not working

Tags: gimp, brush

[image]

No matter what I do my Brush Editor options remain grayed out. I'm trying to edit a custom brush as I know the default ones are read-only.

I have no idea what's causing this, the way that I make new brushes is by copying something and using the Paste as new brush option.

Comment: These sliders only work with some of GIMPs built-in brushes, not custom brushes.

Comment: I'm yet to find a single one that works.

Comment: Some of the sliders work with the 1. Pixel, 2 Block 01, 2 Block 02, 2 Block 03, 2 Hardness 025, 2 Hardness 050, 2 Hardness 075, 2 Hardness 100, 2. Star. Or if you make a new brush in the brushes palette, Brushes Menu > New Brush.

Answer (score 2):

In Gimp there are really two kind of brushes:

1. **bitmap**: these are those you create as an image and export as GBR (or GIH). They can have any shape/color. The "color" ones (for instance, the "Pepper" brush) are used as is, the grayscales ones (saved from a grayscale image) are considered "masks": they assume the foreground color, the white-to-black value indicates opacity. Like all bitmaps they cannot be scaled indefinitely.
2. **parametric**: these are really described internally a bit like paths/vectors. They can be scaled at will but can only have a few simple shapes (circle, square, diamond, star...) and always behave like grayscale brushes.

The brush editor is only meant to create/edit these "parametric" brushes.